# sql - How to store a List with a custom Datatype in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to store this type in my MySQL database:

```
class example{
    int someint,
    string somestring,
}
```

Now I would like to store this datatype in a List in my MySQL database:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| listOfExample   | list<withExampleasDatatype>    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id              | int(11)                        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I hope I do not embarrass myself with this question.

Comment: please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html there is no such thing as a custom data type in mysql

Comment: @P.Salmon how can I put a List<int> in my table then?

Comment: I suggest you don't = its not the sql way.

Comment: @P.Salmon okay thank you, but could you give me any suggestion for storing Lists?

Comment: Just don't sql is table based - burst lists to rows.

Comment: @P.Salmon can i store a table in a other table's row?

Comment: Nope - You need to spend some time with a sql tutorial and you should recast the question stating what you are trying to achieve as opposed to an approach you have settled on.

Comment: MySQL now has a JSON datatype, but I strongly recommend you don't do it. Read about database normalization and put the list in a table where each item is in a separate row, linked to the main table by a foreign key.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, that is what I was looking for. Hopefully I am going to find a good tutorial